# Forçar download de texto em formato aceito pelo MSWord com PHP?

Tags: php, download, header, microsoft-word, mime-type

Gostaria de saber como forçar o *download* de um arquivo, com alguma extensão aceita pelo *Microsoft Word*, através da função **header**.

Pesquisei algumas vezes, testei os MIME types que encontrei, como os que se encontram nesta [lista da Microsoft](https://web.archive.org/web/20160215155254/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx), mas não obtive sucesso.

Este código funciona para forçar o download de um arquivo com extensão **.txt**, mas se tentar com **.doc**, ocorrerá um erro ao tentar abrir, pelo word, o arquivo baixado.

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . uniqid(time()) . '.txt";');
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
```

Exemplo completo:

```
<?php
 
$file = tmpfile();
 
$content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent a vehicula mi, eu lacinia sem. Donec pellentesque egestas pulvinar. Donec ultricies risus vitae tellus tincidunt sagittis sed a odio. Curabitur vitae egestas metus, sit amet consectetur nisi. In pellentesque, mauris consequat ornare ullamcorper, mi nunc condimentum leo, ac feugiat lectus metus in nulla. Nulla ac vestibulum lacus. Donec sit amet felis pulvinar, vestibulum metus at, mattis lorem. Duis efficitur, velit vitae ullamcorper blandit, erat quam vehicula risus, dignissim volutpat nulla orci quis augue. Donec nisi velit, sagittis sed consectetur vitae, ornare eget turpis. Vivamus tincidunt, ligula sit amet aliquet iaculis, sapien risus rutrum purus, a sollicitudin nunc lacus sit amet purus. Pellentesque lacinia, tortor ut rhoncus molestie, eros nisl venenatis turpis, eget elementum quam ligula eget eros. Phasellus aliquam neque blandit scelerisque mattis. Maecenas purus erat, sodales at tincidunt eu, facilisis non velit. Quisque blandit arcu non dolor efficitur hendrerit.
 
Morbi ultricies arcu tempor, convallis sem non, faucibus risus. Praesent ut nunc sit amet quam placerat iaculis non at nibh. Maecenas imperdiet aliquam risus, ut sodales justo consequat id. Donec sollicitudin maximus cursus. Sed placerat, mauris a ornare hendrerit, ipsum enim ornare augue, non efficitur magna nulla auctor mi. Praesent sodales sed erat non luctus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis eget semper augue. Suspendisse pellentesque condimentum vehicula. Aliquam tempor arcu non leo vehicula, vitae ornare tortor sagittis. Vivamus posuere nibh massa, et dapibus nisl viverra quis. Phasellus tincidunt tellus id vehicula varius. Cras efficitur libero vitae accumsan tincidunt.
 
Nam molestie enim non nulla imperdiet interdum. Ut eget tortor venenatis, lobortis est a, consequat leo. Quisque consequat pellentesque velit eget vulputate. Integer pharetra felis sed hendrerit tristique. Donec tempus gravida diam, non maximus metus semper ac. Nulla ultrices egestas turpis. Fusce at dui ligula. Nam eget ligula sit amet quam tincidunt mollis. Mauris vitae dapibus lectus. Vestibulum id purus lacus. Proin tincidunt felis ac suscipit tristique.
 
Maecenas ullamcorper quis risus nec suscipit. Nam sodales tincidunt laoreet. Mauris interdum auctor massa, sit amet blandit nulla ullamcorper hendrerit. Curabitur ante libero, feugiat id iaculis quis, vestibulum ut eros. Morbi eleifend leo vitae mi laoreet eleifend. Ut vel accumsan mi. Cras sit amet bibendum tortor, nec vestibulum risus. Vestibulum suscipit rutrum turpis eu lacinia. Mauris porttitor maximus eros. Nullam augue arcu, sodales et porttitor eget, hendrerit eu odio. Vestibulum suscipit nisi sed commodo posuere. Proin volutpat nunc non neque accumsan posuere. Duis consequat, leo nec dictum sodales, neque leo congue nisl, eget consequat odio dolor eget nunc. Proin accumsan enim nisi.
 
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam egestas hendrerit nisi, tristique pretium velit condimentum vel. Etiam sit amet purus nec risus finibus finibus auctor in metus. Integer nec risus mauris. Fusce aliquet egestas purus sed venenatis. Fusce non finibus sapien. Integer eu augue ligula. Sed urna sapien, hendrerit et pharetra sed, posuere eu elit. Sed a nibh id ipsum scelerisque iaculis. Vestibulum convallis sollicitudin erat ut blandit. Integer scelerisque odio vel nisl ullamcorper, vel feugiat nibh pretium. Sed et lectus vulputate, feugiat lacus vitae, lobortis sem.";
 
fwrite($file, $content);
fseek($file, 0);
 
$metadata = stream_get_meta_data($file);
$filename = $metadata["uri"];
 
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'. uniqid(time()) . '.docx";');
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi... Vc quer transformar um aquivo `.php` em `.doc` pra depois disponibilizar pra download? Se for isso tem o [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)...

Comment: @gustavox Não, quero pegar um texto qualquer, pode ser vindo do banco de dados ou não, e exportá-lo em .doc

Comment: Então, mas explique melhor como quer fazer isso. Função específica no PHP acho que não existe, tenho quase certeza que vc vai precisar do PHPWord mesmo... dá uma olhada.

Comment: With PHPWord, you can create DOCX, ODT, or RTF documents dynamically using your PHP 5.3+ scripts. Below are some of the things that you can do with PHPWord library: [...] **Create header and footer for each sections**

Comment: @gustavox Ok, irei dar uma olhada nessa classe, mas "ouvi dizer" que dava pra forçar o download da mesma forma q um arquivo txt, não sei...

Comment: Tomara que tenha mesmo, seria útil pra mim tbm... :-)

Comment: @gustavox rsrsrs pois é... vou deixar em aberto aqui, ver se surgem mais sugestões

Comment: nah, esqueça tudo o que eu disse antes... veja [isso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487365/http-header-for-downloading-microsoft-word-and-excel-files).

Comment: @ThomersonRoncally Sempre adicione um exemplo funcional do problema, assim facilita as pessoas detectarem a falha, recomendo que leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, removi a parte "se precisarem do codigo comentem" pois sempre coloque o codigo, nao precisa ser completo, ele so precisa "funcionar" e precisa reproduzir o problema (ele deve ser Mínimo, Completo e Verificável) --- Espero que a resposta lhe ajude :) Ate mais.

Comment: @gustavox estranho que o teu segundo comentario diz a resposta (vc vai precisar do PHPWord mesmo), agora que eu vi, nao entendi porque nao adicionou isto a resposta. O exemplo do autor nao vai funciona justamente por isto, ele esta tentando enviar um texto simples pro output e forcar mas com a extensao `.doc`, no entanto softwares como MSword e LibreOffice nao conseguem ler isto. O arquivo docx por exemplo 'e um arquivo zip que contem varios arquivos, dentre eles o principal e um xml (office open xml https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats) :)

Comment: Sim @GuilhermeNascimento, eu já tinha olhado esta biblioteca, é muito boa, mas na época achei meio complicada pra mim... e como o ap falou que era possível, achei que seria muito mais simples usar só o header, já que uma parte do que preciso é só texto mesmo (o PHPWord vai ser melhor se eu conseguir porque ele rendriza todo html né..)... Mas enfim,  então não tem jeito mesmo né, porque no Open Office ele abre, mas ele tá abrindo em asc II né, e o word  do windows não abre assim... saquei. Valeu por enquanto! Abraços. +1

Comment: Em tempo: Eu consegui instalar certinho, e já gero os exemplos que vem na pasta, mas ainda não consegui fazer funcionar com o código gerado dinamicamente do meu formulário, mas acho que isto já seria outra pergunta... Valeu.

Comment: Obrigado @gustavox :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O seu problema não é com a extensão do arquivo ou com o `header` passado, o problema é que você está tentando forçar softwares como o Microsoft Word a ler um arquivo simples de texto ASCII como se fosse um `.doc`.

Arquivos `.docx` e `.docm` são arquivos zipados que usam o [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats), os quais contêm os arquivos (por exemplo) `[Content_Types].xml`, `docProps/core.xml`, `word/document.xml` e a pasta `_rels` que "formam" o arquivo do Word.

Já o arquivo `.doc` é um documento binário que segue um padrão próprio, e existem variações para cada versão do Word, de como ele gera tal documento e a extensão também já foi usada por outros softwares e possuíam formato diferente.

Portanto nem `.doc` e nem `.docx` são arquivos de texto comuns.

> **Nota**: Programas como Abiword e OpenOffice (como citado pelo [@gustavox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86363/for%C3%A7ar-download-de-texto-em-formato-aceito-pelo-msword-com-php#comment174126_86366)) funcionaram pois eles próprios tentam recodificar os arquivos de texto puro para arquivos do tipo `doc` ou `odt` e por isto foi possível visualizar.

Se deseja criar um arquivo `.docx` de verdade com PHP sera necessário uma biblioteca. Uma biblioteca que pode lhe ser útil e o [PHPword](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord).

### Requisitos pra usar o PHPWord

- PHP 5.3+
- [Extensão Zip](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php)
- [XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/xml.installation.php)
- [Extensão XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) (usado pra escrever documentos DOCX e ODT)
- [Extensão GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) (opcional, pra quando adiciona imagens ao documento)
- [Extensão XSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) (opcional, pra aplicar estilos com XSL)
- [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) (opcional, usado pra escrever PDF)

### Usando o PHPWord

Exemplo pra gerar um arquivo `.docx` e fazer download dele:

```
<?php
require_once 'src/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();

$filename = 'helloWorld.docx';

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText(
    htmlspecialchars('Ola mundo!')
);

//Texto com Tahoma e fonte tamanho 10
$section->addText(
    htmlspecialchars('Ola 2'),
    array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 10)
);

$fontStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
$fontStyle->setBold(true);
$fontStyle->setName('Tahoma');
$fontStyle->setSize(13);
$myTextElement = $section->addText(
    htmlspecialchars('"Teste test." (Texto customizado)')
);
$myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyle);

//Salva o documento como word2007 (ou docx)
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save($filename);

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . uniqid(time()) . '.docx";');
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: Realmente, o jeito foi utilizar esta biblioteca, PHPWord, para gerar um arquivo .docx sem corrompê-lo. Agradeço a atenção de todos que responderam... @gustavox, por ter citado a biblioteca PHPWord e pelo empenho nos testes, e ao Guilherme, pelo esclarecimento sobre o problema e como utilizar a biblioteca. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 2):

> UPDATE

Estava tendo alguma dificuldade pra utilizar o PHPWord chamando arquivos HTML externos, e durante a pesquisa por conta de alguns erros acabei encontrando [esta biblioteca sensacional](https://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/).

A utilização é bastante simples. Após fazer o download, descompacte dentro do seu projeto e está pronto. Ela já vem com os arquivos necessários (PHPWord etc, mas vc pode querer baixar as versões atualizadas, o que pra mim complicou então deixei com as que vem por padrão - veja abaixo).

Dentro da pasta há um arquivo `example.php` no qual é preciso alterar apenas esta linha:

```
// HTML fragment we want to parse:
$html = file_get_contents('../arquivo.html');
```

Pra pegar arquivos criados dinamicamente, criei um `while` na página de entrada pra pegar o id do arquivo HTML gerado, e no arquivo `example.php` pego o id pela URL pra escolher o arquivo certo:

```
$numberfile = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

E então:

```
$html = file_get_contents('../arquivo'.$numberfile.'.html');
```

E é só. Claro que este é um exemplo básico, que existem muitas configurações possíveis, e que só vai funcionar com códigos HTML simples, mas é muito mais fácil do que qualquer coisa que encontrei até agora.

(traduzido pelo Google Tradutor)

**Descrição do Projeto**

Este código converte HTML para documentos do Word (formato `docx`). O código é escrito em PHP, e trabalha com PHPWord.

Este conversor é especialmente projetado para tirar HTML simples - o tipo de HTML tipicamente produzido por editores WYSIWYG (como TinyMCE) ou que possam ser incluídos em um blog - e converte-os em um documento do Word `docx`.

O resultado é um documento familiar para a maioria das pessoas que usam documentos do Word e, portanto, fáceis de usar. Não se pretende de maneira alguma recriar complexos layouts de páginas web em um documento do Word.

Este conversor requer SimpleHTMLDom e PHPWord * para a função - cópias de ambos estão incluídos nesta versão (embora você possa querer baixar as últimas versões destes).

Este conversor foi desenvolvido através do projeto Commtap que apoia as pessoas que trabalham com crianças com deficiência de comunicação.

Se você gosta deste conversor,sinta-se livre para doar!

> /UPDATE

Os headers corretos são:

para Excel (*.xlsx):

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $fileName . '"');
```

para Word (*.docx):

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $fileName . '"');
```

*Traduzido [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15703536/4734177) do SOen.

**Update:** Com o `Content-Disposition` da forma acima não estava funcionando, mas seguindo neste ponto [a outra resposta dessa mesma pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11487368/4734177), consegui baixar em `.doc` aqui desta forma:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$No}_{$Name}_{$Test}.docx\"");
```

Comment: Tentei aqui utilizando esses MIME types e não rolou :/ peço que dê uma conferida no [código que disponibilizei no ideone](https://ideone.com/uDNMVm) para, se for o caso, testar aí. Pois ele faz o download do arquivo em `.docx`, mas dá erro ao abrir no word. :/

Comment: @ThomersonRoncally Ah, maldito Windows cara :P, porque aqui no Ubuntu 14.4, usando tanto o Abiword quando o OpenOffice, o arquivo abre perfeitamente usando o código que postaste no ideone... PS: será que o problema não é com alguma configuração do seu Word?

Comment: Só pra constar, quando abro no OpenOffice ele abre uma telinha ASCII Filter Options, com a pré configuração sugerida assim: Unicode:UTF-8 / Default-Fonts: Times New Roman / Language - Português-BR... e clicando com essa pré-configuração mesmo ele abre normalmente... o problema no seu Word pode ser com o Unicode....