# Quais o riscos de se gravar arquivos no servidor Apache com PHP e como evitá-los?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, permissões

Estou gravando um arquivo HTML com parte de uma página, pra ser usado depois pelo [`HTMLDocX`](https://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/) na geração de um arquivo `.docx` (vide [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86363/for%C3%A7ar-download-de-texto-em-formato-aceito-pelo-msword-com-php) relacionada).

Pra gravar uso `ob_start` e `ob_get_clean` pra colocar o conteúdo numa variável:

```
ob_start();

// parte da página aqui

$var = ob_get_clean();
```

E depois com `file_put_contents` salvo o arquivo num diretório do servidor:

```
file_put_contents('/pasta/arquivo'.$id.'.html', $var); // cria o arquivo com o id criado antes.
```

Então, na template do HTMLDocX é só  pegar o arquivo com `file_get_contents`:

```
$html = file_get_contents('../../pasta/arquivo'.$id.'.html');
```

Mas daí que toda vez que vou testar isso no localhost (ainda não passei pro servidor), tenho que mudar a permissão do diretório na unha (com `chmod` e tal). Sei que deve ter uma forma de tornar essa permissão definitiva, ainda não fui ver isso... mas então fiquei pensando que podem  existir sérios riscos de segurança, já que estou dando permissão de escrita a um diretório (777).

Resumindo, a pergunta é:

> Quais são os riscos envolvidos no processo de gravação e
>   posterior acesso de um arquivo `.hmtl` num servidor Apache com PHP, e
>   como evitá-los? Existe uma melhor prática para isso?

No caso seria melhor apenas salvar o HTML no banco e depois acessar pela query do mySQL (faço assim pra gerar o pdf, mas pro docx achei mais simples apenas gravar o arquivo e acessar depois pelo HTMLDocX...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salvar arquivos no servidor é seguro desde que seja configurado corretamente. Utilizar a permissão 777 é uma péssima prática, mas algumas vezes é a única alternativa quando não há permissão de acesso *root*.

O ideal é atribuir permissões de escrita apenas para o servidor (geralmente usuário `www-data`) com `chown` e `chmod`.

Na prática, como é necessário manipular os arquivos (principalmente em ambiente de desenvolvimento), eu utilizo permissões 664 para arquivos e 775 para diretórios, sendo meu usuário o proprietário e o apache o grupo proprietário, da seguinte maneira:

```
drwxrwxr-x 24 meu-usuario www-data  4096 Out 23 13:20 arquivos
-rw-rw-r--  1 meu-usuario www-data  3710 Out 23 13:20 index.php
```

Para configurar o ambiente os comandos são (como *root*):

```
chown -R www-data /var/www/html/
chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/
```

O primeiro altera o grupo proprietário para o servidor de forma recursiva e o segundo adiciona as permissões de escrita para o grupo. Por padrão o grupo já tem permissão de execução (diretórios apenas) e leitura. O diretório `/var/www/html/` é o padrão do apache e seu ambiente pode estar em outro local.

---

Entretanto os arquivos criados pelo apache/PHP não estarão acessíveis pelo seu usuário automaticamente, mas você pode configurar uma tarefa agendada com o commando `crontab -e` (como *root*) e adicionando a linha abaixo no editor para executar a atualização a cada 5 minutos.

```
*/5 * * * * chown -R seu-usuario:www-data /var/www/html/ && chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/
```